# How do you set breakpoints with windbg.?

Tags: windows, windbg, breakpoints

I can not speak English.
Thank you for your understanding.

I would like to set a condition breakpoint on windbg.
I want to set a breakpoint when the value stored at a specific address is changed.

For example,

address:96753008 data: 100

address:96753008 data: 0

As described above, When the value of 96753008 is changed from 100 to 0
I want to set a breakpoint.

I tried the best with Google search, but It was output only when the variable name can be used as a condition.(When there is a pdb file)

Comment: Then you need to improve your Googling skills, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ba--break-on-access-

Comment: ba w 1 96753xxxx  ".if {} .else {}